# Correlation of 2 binary events over time in Excel

Tags: excel, statistics, correlation

I need help determining if 2 events are related.

I have a light on in my back yard meant as a deterrent for deer eating things in my garden, but sometimes it goes off without warning. I have data by date of light ON or OFF.

I have dates of deer snacking in my garden. I want to see if the light is a good deterrent by seeing if the days when the light is off correlates to deer eating my garden.

The tool I have to use is excel.

I want to determine of Light On or Off correlates to Deer Eating Yes or No.

What is the best way to determine this?

I believe I am trying to conduct a correlation of two binary variables over time. I need help with steps in excel on how to do this.

Comment: just a confirmation, 

 (1) you want to know whether or not a deer snacks in your garden when the light goes off in your garden.
 (2) you basically have days when the light is on/off and days when the deer eats in your garden.

Comment: Correct. Does the light being on prevent deer snacking?

Comment: Microsoft has a default Analysis toolpack you can install for free: check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/load-the-analysis-toolpak-in-excel-6a63e598-cd6d-42e3-9317-6b40ba1a66b4). It has several features and one of them is [correlation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-analysis-toolpak-to-perform-complex-data-analysis-6c67ccf0-f4a9-487c-8dec-bdb5a2cefab6)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example of how it works. I made a fake dataset with 3 variables:

**x:** just a bunch or values between 1 and 100, ascending sorted

**y:** It's exactly the square of variable x, to force high correlation

**z:** just random values between 1 and 5

Then get correlation matrix using [Analysis Toolpack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/load-the-analysis-toolpak-in-excel-6a63e598-cd6d-42e3-9317-6b40ba1a66b4)

[image]

To get this, after installing toolpack, go to Data tab--> Analysis toolpack:

[image]

Then choose *Correlation* option (I don't know the exact name in english version):

[image]

Then setup according to your data (my fake dataset is in columns with top row being headers):

[image]

As you can see in the output, variables X and Y are highly correlated (as expected) but Z is not at all (as expected too).

Anyways, remember that [high correlation does not mean causation](https://amplitude.com/blog/causation-correlation#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20correlation,action%20A%20causes%20outcome%20B.)

Comment: Is that the best approach for 2 binary variables of 0 or 1?

Comment: There is not a definitve approach, just different approaches. What have you designed to properly approach this? What have you tried? What are you obtaining and what does not make sense?